# Annuity/Finance

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

I'm trying to determine the question below:

**Mr. Learnwell wants to setup a scholarship of $4500 paid at the end of every six months. If the interest rate is 6.4% compounded semi-anually, how much must Mr. Learnwell pay into the scholarship fund now.**

I've got the formula:

$A = R \cdot \frac{1-(1+i)^{-n}}{i}$

So therefore $A=4500\frac{1-(1+0.032)^{-2}}{0.032} = 8585.72$

I'm not too sure if this is the right formula or answer. Could i get some advice?

Comment: Your formula means nothing until you tell us what $A$ stands for, what $R$ stands for, what $i$ stands for, and what $n$ stands for.

Comment: But it seems to me that if the idea is to pay out \$4,500 every six months forever, then the interest earned every 6 months must be \$4,500. So the question is, 3.2 percent of what is \$4,500? $(.032)x=4500$, solve for $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The future value ok. : $FV_1=4500\cdot \frac{1.032^2-1}{0.032}$

To get the present value, I would discount the future value once, with a interest rate of $i=0.064$

$PV=4500\cdot \frac{1.032^2-1}{0.032}\cdot \frac{1}{1.064}$

You discounted the future value two times with the semi-annually interest rate of $i_2=0.032$

$\tilde{PV}=4500\cdot \frac{1.032^2-1}{0.032}\cdot \frac{1}{1.032^2}=4500\cdot \frac{1-1.032^{-2}}{0.032}$

I think it is more logical to take the annually interest rate, because the PV is independent from the way the FV come about.